# Analysis of 90% threads in java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, thread-dump

Thread count in my tomcat application server is **growing** every day.

When I have taken thread dump for analysis.

**I found that out of 430 threads 307 threads are with this status.**

**Sample stacktrace**

```
"pool-283-thread-1" #2308674 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000a916800 nid=0x1101 waiting on condition [0x00002aec87f17000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d9929ec0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"pool-282-thread-1" #2307106 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000a4fb000 nid=0x78e3 waiting on condition [0x00002aec87e16000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d8ca7bf8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

**Environment**

```
JDK: jdk1.8.0_60
OS: Linux
Tomcat: tomcat-7.0.65
```

Not sure if this is causing the issue.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Those threads appear to be a thread pool waiting for a task in a queue.  I think you'll have to tell us how you setup that thread pool and queue.

Comment: Do you happen to miss a shutdown on a threadpool/ExecutorService?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is typical resource leak. You are using some sort of `ExecutorService` somewhere in your application and you are not closing that pool after work is done causing threads to await forever.

You should call `ExecutorService#shutdown()` to close pool and release/terminate its threads after work is done.

Threads names like `pool-282-thread-1` `pool-283-thread-1` suggests that you are most probably using single thread pool executor (because pool no. is large and thread no. is only 1). The idea behind `ExecutorService` is to reuse threads that are idle to do some more work. So insteed of createing new `ExecutorService` each time you need to do some background work, you should rather share single instance and use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened in our application. We fixed it by using **single ExecutorService** instead of creating **ExecutorService** each time.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, welcome to SO.  Please be sure to read the rules while you're here.  Answers should be left to answers to the question, not +1 or thanks posts.  If you could add some code to show your solution it would help this post a lot.  Cheers!